# Dataframe .iloc low speed peformance

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas library and I am having some problems with performance using .iloc on pandas.

The idea for main software is to search in each row and column of dataframe and if reach in any condition, update this specific row and column of this dataframe with a new value.

Below follow some lines of this code:

```
for cont, val in enumerate(id_truck_list):
    print cont
    for index, row in all_travel.iterrows():
        id_tr = int(all_travel.iloc[index, 0])
        begin = all_travel.iloc[index, 5]
        end = all_travel.iloc[index, 11]
        if int(val) == id_tr:
            #print "test1"
            #print id_tr
            #print begin_list[cont]
            #print begin
            #print end_list[cont]
            #print end
            if begin_list[cont] >= begin:
                if  end_list[cont] <= begin:
                    pass
                else:
                    #print 'h1'
                    all_travel.iloc[index, 18] =  all_travel.iloc[index, 18] + 3 
            else:
                if begin < end_list[cont] :
                    if end <= end_list[cont]:
                        #print 'h2'
                        #print(all_travel.iloc[index, 18])
                        all_travel.iloc[index, 18] = all_travel.iloc[index, 18] + 5
                        #print(all_travel.iloc[index, 18])
                        #print str(index)
                    else:
                        #print 'h3'
                        all_travel.iloc[index, 18] = all_travel.iloc[index, 18] + 7
                else:
                    pass
```

This idea is performing in very slow way (more or less 10 rows per minute). Do you have any idea using pandas library

Below follow the all_travel.head()

```
truck_id  id_farm gatec_dist gps_go_dist gps_ret_dist             t1gatec  \
0  2010028.0     76.0         11     11.8617     0.211655 2016-03-09 00:24:00   
1  2010028.0      1.0       16.2        9.86    0.0637544 2016-03-13 23:57:00   
2  2010028.0     75.0         18       10.78         9.65 2016-03-18 09:17:00   
3  2010028.0     62.0          6     8.51291      3.99291 2016-03-19 20:16:00   
4  2010028.0     62.0          6        2.91    0.0428008 2016-03-21 03:00:00   

             t1gps t2gatec                t2gps t3gatec  \
0  03/09/2016 00:09:58       0  03/09/2016 00:43:46       0   
1  03/13/2016 23:46:00       0  03/14/2016 00:53:10       0   
2  03/18/2016 09:13:15       0  03/18/2016 10:17:14       0   
3  03/19/2016 20:29:59       0  03/19/2016 21:22:40       0   
4  03/21/2016 02:49:34       0  03/21/2016 03:38:59       0   

             t3gps             t4gatec                t4gps   wait_mill  \
0  03/09/2016 07:00:15 2016-03-09 02:14:55  03/09/2016 02:14:55  154.500000   
1  03/14/2016 13:54:30 2016-03-14 01:12:58  03/14/2016 01:12:58  124.733333   
2  03/18/2016 12:07:00 2016-03-18 12:37:41  03/18/2016 12:44:01  408.316667   
3  03/19/2016 23:57:22 2016-03-19 22:00:08  03/19/2016 22:00:08  256.083333   
4  03/22/2016 00:09:56 2016-03-21 04:01:20  03/21/2016 04:01:20   47.333333   

go_field   wait_field     ret_mill    tot_trav  maintenance_level  
0  33.800000   376.483333  -285.333333  124.950000                  1  
1  67.166667   781.333333  -761.533333   86.966667                  1  
2  63.983333   109.766667    37.016667  210.766667                  1  
3  52.683333   154.700000  -117.233333   90.150000                  1  
4  49.416667  1230.950000 -1208.600000   71.766667                  1
```

Comment: Can you post df.head(). Its usually easier to work with a snapshot of the dataframe rather than the code

Comment: @A-Za-z I updated my question with the head of dataframe

Comment: Cool, another qn - what do you mean by "if reach in any condition?"

Comment: @A-Za-z in the code is more clear. In the code it compares the ID of equipment (if int(val) == id_tr) and the period of time, using two datetimes (t1gatec, t4gatec)

Comment: @RaphaelCastilhoGil, the best way to speed up the loops in Pandas / Numpy / SciPy is ... to get rid of them. Please provide a sample (3-5 rows) input data set(s) in a TEXT/CSV form (so we could copy & paste it for coding) a short description of what you are going to achieve and desired data set.

Answer (score 0):

I have done another solution that has improved a lot my speed performance.
I changed parts of dataframe to list, due the better performance using lists against normal dataframe.
The conclusion, now I need to wait two minutes for the answer, not 3 days.

Bellow follow the modification

```
for cont, val in enumerate(id_truck_list):
    for cont2, val2 in enumerate(id_truck_list2):
        id_tr = int(id_truck_list2[cont2])
        begin = begin_list2[cont2]
        end = end_list2[cont2]
        if int(id_truck_list[cont]) == id_tr:
            if begin_list[cont] >= begin:
                if  begin_list[cont] >= end:
                    pass
                else:
                    maintenance_list[cont2] =  maintenance_list[cont2] + 3
            else:
                if begin < end_list[cont] :
                    if end <= end_list[cont]:
                        #print 'h2'
                        maintenance_list[cont2] = maintenance_list[cont2] + 
                        #print str(index)
                    else:
                        #print 'h3'
                        maintenance_list[cont2] = maintenance_list[cont2] + 
                else:
                    pass

print 'list size ' + str(len(maintenance_list))
for cont3, val3 in enumerate(maintenance_list):
    print 'list update  ' + str(cont3)
    all_travel.iloc[cont3, 18] = maintenance_list[cont3]
```